# How should we handle recursive getter/setter StackOverflowException questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, typographical-error

Periodically questions are posted where the OP uses a property in its getter/setter which leads to recursive calls and results in `StackOverflowException`. The most recent one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64692969/stack-overflow-on-collection-c-sharp).

How should we handle such questions?

In my opinion, these are typos and have to be closed: instead of typing the backing field name, the OP has typed the property name. I guess every programmer has to face this error once. Some of them (those *hopeless* kind) will ask a question on Stack Overflow, and it means there will be hundreds of such questions, not linked, not shown as relevant, etc.

Closing a question as duplicate is an option too. We have [a canonical duplicate for NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)), but I am unable to find one for `StackOverflowException`.

Yet, every such question (at least from my experience) receives an answer, which in my opinion is wrong.

Comment: For this particular one I would Have choose : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437791/overloading-getter-and-setter-causes-stackoverflow-in-c-sharp, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276156/stack-overflow-exception-in-c-sharp-setter

Comment: Shouldn't those be asked on meta? /s

Comment: Hm. StackOverflowException could refer to at least two wildly different scenarios; it is the result of infinite recursion, but it can also be the result of an actual stack-like collection overflowing. Infinite recursion is very likely the scenario we are talking about here, so in my opinion an answer which is about recursion and covers the topic of infinite recursion could service as a canonical.

Comment: @Gimby, I am not aware about second scenario, do you mean collection itself will throw `StackOverflowException` in one of its methods or what? Do you have an example?

Comment: @Sinatr My point was that this is about (infinite) recursion, not specifically about a StackOverflowException.

Comment: Are you talking about the specific one (StackOverflowException - C# only? Java too?) or stack overflow ***exceptions*** in general? Or even broader, stack overflows in general (e.g. undefined behaviour in (stone-age) C)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, thanks for fixing grammar and videos. Lundin has already correctly identified my question as C# specific in [his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402670/1997232). But maybe language-agnostic duplicate is not a bad idea? What if language specific answers can be then posted there with specific common mistakes?

Comment: Should this be just a canonical for the specific case of recursively-called getter/setter only? Or all kinds of stack overflow (perhaps it can explain what stack overflow is, but would there be a sizable component who already knows what's it already)?

Comment: Wow, it me a long time reading through the question and comments to realise there was no connection between "StackOverflowException" and the name of this site.

Comment: I wonder: If you create a stack overflow as a programmer, and you are looking for help, does it surprise that you may end up at a site named `stackoverflow.com`? I mean one could answer in this sense: "*While stackoverflow is here to help for any kind of programming problems, stack overflows are the consequence of unwanted direct or indirect recursion most of the time*". And we'd need *one* good answer how to avoid unwanted recursion and how to do intended recursion right.

Comment: I once had a stack overflow issue and I tried to search first, like a good person. Alas... However useful this site may be, it made it impossible to find the answer to that particular problem.

Comment: Your example is very specific to C#, most languages don't have properties. In other languages, people tend to notice trivial endless recursions a bit more.

Comment: And here I am, not knowing anything about stack overflow the programming problem, thinking StackOverflowException is some kind of April fool's joke or something related to Stack Overflow the website.

Answer (score 25):

Have the C# community settle for a canonical dupe. As mentioned in comments, these look like potentially good candidates:

[Overloading getter and setter causes a stack overflow in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437791/overloading-getter-and-setter-causes-stackoverflow-in-c-sharp)
[Stack overflow exception in C# setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276156/stack-overflow-exception-in-c-sharp-setter)
(Maybe edit the titles of these questions into shape, review tags and so on.)

Or if no good-enough canonical dupe exists, then make one:

- Post it as a self-answered community wiki.
- (You can flag the question to have both Q + A set as community wiki by a diamond mod)
- You could even post a draft here on meta and have it peer reviewed in advance, preferably by a number of C# gurus/gold badge holders.

Once settled which one to use as canonical dupe, add a link to it below the FAQ at the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info), for easy access by other user moderators.